# Two Way School Timetable Schema

Tags: sql, database

Hi to anyone reading this!

I really need help with creating a two way timetable database via SQL or Microsoft Access! I've did my homework of course by googling but the answers didn't seem clear enough and weren't very good. I've also attempted to make an ERD Diagram  and prototyped my database but that didn't go too well unfortunately I attempted to make one but it didn't make sense to me so I ended up deleting it.

So basically I would want to create a two way timetable where there is week 1 or A and week 2 or B! Which would be pretty much like this website: http://timetable2calendar.com/two-week-timetable-beta/
I'll need to make it somehow retrieve the current date and make it find out whether it's week 1 or 2.

For example:

If it's

1/09/2014 then it would be week 1 or A.

If it's
8/09/2014 then it would be week 2 or B.

So here would be my tables:

```
**Student:**

StudentID [PK]

Forename 

Lastname 

Year

Group



**Subject:**

SubjectID [PK]

Subject

Room


**Educator:**

EducatorID [PK]

Forename

Lastname
```

So far this was the easiest part but now I've came across the difficult part of how I'd sort it. Here's was my bad attempt, I've tried looking at schemas and other ERD diagrams but they don't have what I'm looking for.

```
Student Timetable:
TimetableID [PK]
StudentID [FK]
SubjectID [FK]
EducatorID [FK]
Weekday (e.g. Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu, Fri)
Period (Peroid 1 - 08:45, Peroid 2 - 09:15, Peroid 3 - 10:00 etc..)
Week (is it Week 1 or 2?)
```

If anyone could help me with I'd kindly appreciate it. Please don't suggest open source software that does this, I want to create a database for it.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want somebody to design an ER diagram?

Comment: I cannot quite understand the business problem. What is a "Subject", the general id of a field of study or a course offering? If a course offering, does that mean a course may be offered more than once in a single academic year period (which would mean tracking "sections"). If a course offereing can it be offered in future academic periods (as is usually the case), which means tracking the general idea of the coures as well as when it is offered? What do you mean by "timetable"? Is that to layout the points in time when a coures offering will offer classes?

Comment: By "A" and "B" do mean a course has alternating weekly schedules, with certain meeting times/locations one week but different the next week, and then returning to the first week for the third, and so on? If so, are you trying to define the template of each of the pair of week patterns, or is the goal to realize a specific list of all the date-times of all class meetings for all the weeks of the academic period?

Comment: @Bulat My question was how would I design a two way school timetable? An ER diagram would be very helpful though I already done it by the given answer. As well as come up with a solution to determine the week number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on your approach, you may normalize Person.

Your "bad attempt" was on the right track.  One can improve on it by normalizing date and adding location.  The business key (a.k.a. primary key) gets completed by the start time.

```
Person
    PersonID [PK]
    Forename
    Lastname

Student
    StudentID [PK]
    PersonID [FK]
    Year
    Group

Educator
    EducatorID [PK]
    PersonID [FK]


Subject 
    SubjectID [PK]
    SubjectName


Location
    LocationID [PK]
    Room Number
    Building    

Calendar    
    CalendarDate [PK]
    DayOfWeek   
    WeekNumber

Timetable
    SubjectID [PK][FK] 
    CalendarDate[PK][FK]
    LocationID [PK][FK]
    StudentID [PK][FK]
    EducatorID [PK][FK]
    StartTime [PK]
    EndTime
```

Additionally, here's a SQL Server Query to populate the Calendar table data:

```
DECLARE @CalendarStartDate DATETIME, @MonthsToGenerate INT
SELECT @CalendarStartDate = '2010-01-01', @MonthsToGenerate = 60;


WITH CalendarCTE (CalendarDate,DayOfWeek,WeekNumber)
AS (
    SELECT @CalendarStartDate AS CalendarDate, DATEPART(weekday,@CalendarStartDate) AS DayOfWeek , DATEPART(week,@CalendarStartDate) AS WeekNumber
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day,1,CalendarDate) AS CalendarDate, DATEPART(weekday,DATEADD(day,1,CalendarDate)) AS DayOfWeek , DATEPART(week,DATEADD(day,1,CalendarDate))  AS WeekNumber
    FROM CalendarCTE
    WHERE DATEADD(day,1,CalendarDate) < DATEADD(month,@MonthsToGenerate,@CalendarStartDate) 
)
SELECT *
FROM CalendarCTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

I've also placed it on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20d15/2/0).

Comment: Thank you so much for the normalised tables, things make so much sense! This does answer my question, though is there a way which could automatically generate the week number?

Comment: Hi, I've tried running the query but nothing didn't seem to happen and it returned with an error. (I tested it with SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c9a57/1/0). I'm note sure if I did something wrong though please see link stated (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c9a57/1/0).

Thanks.